# Publishing jar in Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I've been reading about publishing jar in the [**Gradle manual page**](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N103DE) (section 7.2.4).
The following code is provided:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories{
        flatDir{
            dirs 'repos'
        }
    }
}
```

I added that piece of code in my build script but there is no repos dir was created in my project-root directory after `gradle build` was executed. What does it actual do? Is there a documentation for `uploadArchive` and the others methods?

Comment: the next line in the docs says "To publish the JAR file, run gradle uploadArchives.".  Have you done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the section *7.2.4. Publishing the JAR file*, in the mentioned docs suggests, the file is not uploaded by the `build` but by the task `uploadArchives`.

> To publish the JAR file, run `gradle uploadArchives`.

Further in the documentation there are the chapters *8.6. Publishing artifacts* (with an example how to publish to ivy and maven (Example 8.8, 8.9)) and *52.4. Publishing artifacts*.

The task is of type [`Upload`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.html), where one can delve deeper for how the task is working.